# Why cursor is fetching a particular value in a table twice in the below PLSQL block?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR C IS SELECT ENAME FROM EMP;
  v_ename VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN 

   OPEN C;
   LOOP
     FETCH C INTO v_ename; 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ename);
     EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;                        
  CLOSE C;                        
END;                                                                     
/
```

**I need to understand why it is returning SOM twice when it occurs only once in the table.**

```
KING                                 
BLAKE
CLARK                                  
JONES                                 
SCOTT       
FORD                            
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
MARTIN
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES                               
MILLER                                
ABC                            
DEF                             
SOM                           
SOM                            

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Table content :

```
ENAME                                    
--------
ABC                                   
ADAMS                              
ALLEN                             
BLAKE                           
CLARK  
DEF                              
FORD    
JAMES                              
JONES                             
KING                         
MARTIN                             
MILLER                             
SCOTT                            
SMITH                           
SOM                         
TURNER 
WARD
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the loop-breaking condition in the wrong place. It should come before the call to the `PUT_LINE` procedure, not after it.

The way you have it, the last record in the cursor is read, and the line is printed. At this point `C%NOTFOUND` is still `false`. Then the loop is entered one more time; no record is found, so `C%NOTFOUND` becomes `true` - but you only check for it **after** the `PUT_LINE` procedure is executed one more time, with the then-current value of `v_ename` (which is not changed from the previous execution). Only after this additional and unwanted execution of printing a line do you check to see if you should leave the loop.

Move the `EXIT...` command above the `PUT_LINE` call and you will get what you need.